# When testing angularjs controller - Can't find variable: module / inject by chutzpah

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, jasmine, chutzpah

I have angularJs controller

```
angular.module('App.ctrl.guests', [])
    .controller('guestsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$timeout', 'guestsService', function ($scope, $http, $location, $timeout, guestsService) {
        $scope.tiles = [];
    }])
```

and jasmine test

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../../ProjectWeb/Scripts/app/guests/guestsCtrl.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine.js" />
'use strict';
describe('App.ctrl.guests', function () {
    var scope, controller;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('App.ctrl.guests')
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('guestsController', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should have empty array', function () {
        expect(scope.tiles).toBe([]);
    });
})
```

and every time i run in Visual studio chutzpah i get:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module in
>   file:///.../JasmineTests/guestsControllerTest.js
>   (line 5)
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: inject in
>   file:///.../JasmineTests/guestsControllerTest.js (line 12)

Is thera a problem with reference angular.js and jasmine dont know what is module/inject keywords? It is my first time with js testing :/

Comment: Have you included references to the libraries? Not using Visual Studio myself but I think this guy is doing the same setup as you http://www.rosher.co.uk/post/2013/10/22/Unit-Testing-AngularJS-with-Jasmine-Chutzpah-and-Visual-Studio.aspx

Comment: Yes, I add references, I update code.

Comment: Thank You gillesc, I fount in this article to drag and drop js files to test file and now paths are correct ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found in [this](http://www.rosher.co.uk/post/2013/10/22/Unit-Testing-AngularJS-with-Jasmine-Chutzpah-and-Visual-Studio.aspx) article on how to drag and drop JavaScript files for testing and correct path.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article, it is very precise and worked in first try.
Couldn't thanks the author as comments are closed in that article.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact exception a couple of minutes ago on our TFS build server. It turns out that this exception is also occurring when the 'Copy to Output Directory' option in the Properties dialog is set to another option than 'Do not copy'. In our situation, a couple of files was tested from the \bin folder, which lead to an incorrect reference path.